# Refining the search results based on the filters

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, search

I am working on an e-commerce website. While displaying the available mobiles, user can filter the results by the following filters:

1. **Brand name**

   - Samsung
   - Nokia
   - HTC
   - (and many more)
2. **Price range**

   - $100-$200
   - $200-$300
   - (and so on)
3. **Category**

   - Android Mobiles
   - Low cost mobiles
   - Music Phones
   - 3G Phones
   - ...(and many more)

I want to use the following GET parameters to generate a sql query which will execute everytime a filter is applied. Suppose the current filter is `Brand=Samsung` then my link will be http://xyz.com/mobiles.php?brand=samsung

For the above filters, PHP code for generating the SQL query is as follows (using lots of `if/else` statements and `isset()` function):

```
$sql = "SELECT * from items ";
if(isset($_GET['brand']))
{
     $sql = $sql . "where brand=".$_GET['brand']." ";
/*similar statements*/
}
```

Please don't go on the accuracy of the above PHP statements, I have not mentioned the full code. Finally I have the following SQL generated which will provide the result:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS 
WHERE 
     BRAND=SAMSUNG;
```

This SQL query will result the matching products and I will display the results on webpage accordingly. Please answer the following questions:

1. After the above filters (brand), suppose price filter is also applied. How
   can I know that `brand` filter is already there so
   that I can redirect the user to

   http://xyz.com/mobiles.php?brand=samsung&priceMin=100&priceMax=200

   **INSTEAD OF THE FOLLOWING URL**

   http://xyz.com/mobiles.php?priceMin=100&priceMax=200

   i.e. how can i just append the price criteria to the url?
2. Is there any software/library/code available to filter the products?
3. Is there any better way to filter out products or any better way to
   generate the SQL than the method I mentioned above?

I am using PHP, MySQL, Apache on Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try answer your question

1.If user already filter for specific brand, simply save the brand in the session variable

```
$sql = "SELECT * from items ";
if(isset($_GET['brand']))
{
    $_SESSION['brand'] = $_GET['brand'];
    //your code 
}
```

Then in next request check for the existence of that variable

```
if($_SESSION['brand'])
{
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?brand=' . $_SESSION['brand'];
    header( 'Location:' . $url );
    exit;
}
```

2.I didnt aware of..

3.You can build better query by adding `WHERE 1=1`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1=1";

if($_GET['brand')
{
    $query .= " AND brand={$_GET['brand'}";
}

//another condition perhaps
```

Comment: For the first question: after setting URL using `$url` variable, I should append the new criteria (price) to the URL...right?? If yes, then how to redirect the user to the `$url` ?

Comment: @iSummitG yes you should append the new criteria..i just show u rough idea and use header() to redirect user

Comment: @slieer Thank you so much for the answer. Instead of storing SESSION variable, can't I use `isset($_GET('brand'))` ? If the `brand` is set then I can append the new filter accordingly, if not then I will use the only the new criteria. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @iSummitG i dont know detail implementation of your search form.and if $_GET['brand'] exist on every request, simply use it..why bother with session

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to build a dispatch table that calls a function for each query parameter.  This allows you to create a whitelist of safe query parameters.  I would also use parameterized statements to help guard against SQL injection (something that your existing code is not protected against).  [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) makes using parameterized statements easy.

Creating a separate function for each query parameter may seem unnecessary at first, but it means that you can put all your conditions in a separate file, thus keeping your main query function tidy.  It also makes future enhancements easier to implement.

The following is an off-the-top-of-my-head rough example.  It's not meant to be ready to cut and paste into an application.  It's just to give you an idea of what I mean.  In a real app, amongst other things, you'd need to include error checking, and would likely move the database connection stuff elsewhere.

```
// ** query_params.php **

function query_brand () {
    return "brand = ?";
}

function query_price () {
    return "price BETWEEN ? AND ?";
}

function query_category () {
    return "category = ?";
}

// ** product_search.php **

function search () {

    // Build a test GET array.
    $_GET = array(
        'brand'    => 'HTC',
        'price'    => array(100, 200),
        'category' => 'Android Mobiles'
    );

    // Build a dispatch table of safe query parameters.
    $dispatch = array(
        'brand'    => 'query_brand',
        'price'    => 'query_price',
        'category' => 'query_category'
    );

    // An array to hold the conditions.
    $cond = array();

    // An array to hold the bind values.
    $bind = array();

    foreach ( $_GET as $param => $value ) {
        if( isset($dispatch[$param]) ) {
            $cond[] = call_user_func( $dispatch[$param] );
            $bind[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT item, brand, price, category " .
           "FROM products";

    if( count($cond) ) {
        // Combine the conditions into a string.
        $where = implode( ' OR ', $cond );
        $sql .= " WHERE $where";
    }

    // Use PDO to connect to the database.  This should
    // probably be done somewhere else.
    $dbh = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass,
    );

    // Prepare the SQL statement.
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

    // Execute the statement, passing the values to be
    // bound to the parameter placeholders.
    $stmt->execute( $bind );

    // Fetch and return results...
}
```